# Android-java vs PC-Java

Tags: java, android

This simple line of code gives the error "The method getTextContent() is undefined for the type Element":

```
String color_string = ( ( Element )( ( Element )inner_node ).getElementsByTagName( "color" ).item( 0 ) ).getTextContent();
```

I get the error in my Android-java version, but not in my PC-Java which I use for testing and debugging Java code before I run it on the phone.

I have

```
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
```

on both versions.  And I copied the code from the PC-Java to the Android-Java so I am 100% sure I have the same syntax on both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) says there is such a method defined for the `Element` class. So perhaps you are missing some libraries, or have a wrong version.

Comment: Actually it doesn't seem like there is a getTextContent() method for Element in Android. I can't find it.

Comment: @Espen - click my link and find it. It's there. Which version of android SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using API level 7. Anyway, I've rewritten it to String color_string = ( ( Element )inner_node ).getElementsByTagName( "color" ).item( 0 ).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

Comment: Indeed.  If you visit the linked page, check "filter by API level", select level 7, and refresh the page, the `getTextContent` method gets greyed out.

Comment: @StepenC yes, that clear things. But he didn't mention he was using a non-latest version :)

Comment: This is weird. I cannot see it even greyed out. And believe me, I was looking, only 4 methods are greyed out and getTextContent() is not one of them. Anyway, thanx guys, but I will still be using level 7 to get a wider target.

Comment: @Espen - are you looking at the javadoc for the Node class?  That is where the method is declared ... in level 8.

Comment: @Stephen C: Thanx. I see it. I simply thought the method was declared in Element.

Answer (score 2):

@Aspen - the answer is that you are using the wrong libraries on your PC.  You should be compiling your application against Android level 7 libraries, not against Sun Java libraries.

You should be able to correct this for test compiles by downloading the relevant Android JARs and putting them on your compilation bootclasspath.  But I would NOT recommend trying to run code like this on a PC Java platform.  (It *might* work, but you might also end up chasing lots of problems caused by doing this.)

**EDIT**

A better idea might be to use Eclipse with the ADT plugin, as described on [this page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Comment: I am using Eclipse with the ADT plugin. I have level 7 and 8 libraries. Building level 7 for a wider target. Testing this on the Sun Java libraries simply becasue I can use the System.out and see what the DOM gets in the Eclipse console. On Sun Java it works. Moving the code to Android Java and it does not work. Any other aspect of my code compiles and run on my phone - except for the getTextContent() which gives an error in Eclipse. It now seem like it's a level 7 thing.

Answer (score 2):

after checking a lot and scratching my head thousands of times I came up with simple alteration that it needs to change your API level to 8

Comment: yes the getTextContent() method was introduced in API level 8

Answer (score 0):

Android Java is not Sun Java. Androids Java based on Apaches Harmony project (Re-Implementation of Sun Java under an open license).  Some details can be different.

[Wiki](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28Betriebssystem%29) has a list of the java packages and their origins.